# Contiguous Cell Value in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to compare contiguous cell values with single cell? For example:

```
If Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E4:E6").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D4").Value Then

....
```

I tried this but showing error `TYPEMISMATCH`

Comment: You cannot make this comaparison.

Comment: @user2063626, If you're smart you can see my answer.

Comment: @glh wow... miracle... comaring range of cells with a cell value is not possible. (If Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E4:E6").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D4").Value Then)

Comment: @glh using a loop is smartness :-) enjoy

Comment: @user1995151, vbscript is not the language you are using as this is used for use in html and command prompt although similaritys exist. Vba is the language ms office give their macros, etc. and stands for Visual Basic for Applications.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E4:E6").Value` returns a two dimensional array containing the Values in those cells.  You can't compare a value to an array with the equal operator as you've seen.

If you want to see if that value exists, you can use the Match worksheet function like this

```
Sub FindMatch()

    Dim lMatch As Long

    On Error Resume Next
        lMatch = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("D4").Value, Range("E4:E6").Value, False)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If lMatch > 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Value exists"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Not included"
    End If

End Sub
```

If you're trying to determine if all the values in the range are the same, you can use Sumif like this

```
Sub FindAllMatch()

    Dim dSum As Double

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("E4:E6")) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("E4:E6"), Range("D4").Value) Then
        Debug.Print "All match"
    Else
        Debug.Print "One doesn't match"
    End If

End Sub
```

Another option is the Filter VBA function that returns an array filtered on some criteria.  Filter requires a 1-d array and Range().Value returns a 2-d array, so you have to use the Transpose function to make that conversion.

```
Sub Findmatch2()

    Dim vaOneD As Variant
    Dim sMatch As String

    sMatch = Range("D4").Value

    vaOneD = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("E4:E6").Value)

    If UBound(Filter(vaOneD, sMatch, True)) > -1 Then
        Debug.Print "There's a match"
    Else
        Debug.Print "No match"
    End If

End Sub
```

To check if all of the value are the same, change the appropriate line to

```
If UBound(Filter(vaOneD, sMatch, True)) - LBound(Filter(vaOneD, sMatch, True)) = UBound(vaOneD) - LBound(vaOneD) Then
```

Comment: The `sum` will not work for non numerical cell values, you should use `countif` instead. Much better than my `for-loop`. ;)

Comment: Yes, `COUNTIF` is much better.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E4:E6") = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D4").Value
```

If not then you need a for loop:

```
c = true
for each i in Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E4:E6")
    If i <> Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D4").Value then
        c = false
        Exit for
    End if
Next
 If c then
.....
```